# I can't remove Lucida Grande from Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: fonts

I installed Lucida Grande but now I want to remove it.

I checked usr/share/font folder but I still can't find the font.

Any suggestion to remove the font?

(I searched for the file: `Lucida Grande.ttf` but still can't find anything)

Comment: Have you searched your home folder?Goto your home folder,press **Ctrl+H** and see .fonts directory..

Comment: How did you install the font? Did you look in $HOME/.fonts/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this font, wherever it is, whis this line of bash:

```
find /usr/share /home/ | grep [Ll]ucida.*ttf$
```

Usually, fonts are stored in either `/usr/share/fonts/` or `/home/<username>/.fonts`, or **any** of their sub-directories (directories like `ttf` or `otf` are purely cosmetic, for most apps).

Comment: Thanks I totally forgot about the /home/<username> folder thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could install a Gnome font manager:

```
sudo apt-get install font-manager
```

And then

```
Applications->Graphics->Font Manager
```

Then find the "Manage fonts" button on the bottom to remove fonts.
Does this help?